# Flutter How to use Phone Passcode in my app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, passwords, passcode

I want to use the phone's built-in passcode in my app using flutter. I've looked everywhere but couldn't seem to find anything regarding this. What I need help with is how to use flutter to get the phone's passcode and then use that passcode as the PIN to access the app. Please let me know if you know anything or if this is even possible.

Comment: You need to find out how to use ios's Local Authentication Framework in Flutter

Comment: Check this out https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

Comment: Have you got any solution for this one? @Lee3 We've tried with this package but not able to get to phone passcode lock. Can you redirect us to some guide?

Comment: The ability to use PIN/Pattern/Passcode is currently under review and appears close to being added to the package. Please keep an eye out for the next version. I will as well and post here when it is available.